# How to make the BorderThickness receive its value from a WPF resource key?

Tags: wpf, resources, border, thickness

I try to create `String`, `Int32` resource as below but it doesn't work. I got the error saying that the value can't be converted.

If you know how to do this please help.

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="MyKey">1</sys:Int32>
</ResourceDictionary>

<Label Content="abb" BorderThickness="{StaticResource MyKey}" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type of `BorderThickness` is [System.Windows.Thinkness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness.aspx) not `Int32`

```
<Thickness x:Key="MyKey" >1</Thickness>
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried and see that the `Thickness` tag is built-in and we don't need the namespace `win` when we already use the two default namespace `xmlns` and `xmln:x`. Thank you!